# convert pytorch model to ONNX

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, yolo, onnx

How to convert a pytorch model to ONNX? I am trying to use [this method](https://wandb.ai/wandb/common-ml-errors/reports/How-to-Save-and-Load-Models-in-PyTorch--VmlldzozMjg0MTE#load) on Python 3.7:

```
import torch

model = torch.load("./yolov7x.pt")

#torch.onnx.export(model, "yolo_v7x.onnx")
```

Even with the commented last line in the 3 lines of code, loading this errors out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\convert_onx.py", line 5, in <module>
    model = torch.load("./yolov7x.pt")
  File "C:\Users\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 594, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "C:\Users\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 853, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

This is the [git repo](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7#performance) I am working with the Yolo Model 7x:
[image]

Ultimate use case is to use this model on Intel's Open VINO toolkit that requires PyTorch models to be converted to ONYX.

Comment: May be related to https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/18325

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Yolo v7 repo: https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7

Just use the [Google Collab notebooks](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7#:%7E:text=pytorch%20to%20onnx%20with%20nms%20(and%20inference)) provided in the Yolo v7 repo to convert the pytorch to different model types...easy as pie!

Answer (score 2):

When you are loading the pickled model the source tree must match the one that used when the model was saved. So

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'
```

expects this directory to be in your python path: https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/tree/main/models

To export to ONNX:

1. Clone the repo https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7

```
git clone https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7
```

2. Set the correct path to it.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, './yolov7')
```

or you can set `PYTHONPATH` environment variable

3. Also you may need to have specific `torch` version. I've checked and it seems `torch==1.8.0` works fine

Example:

```py
import torch
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, './yolov7')

device = torch.device('cpu')
model = torch.load('yolov7x.pt', map_location=device)['model'].float()
torch.onnx.export(model, torch.zeros((1, 3, 640, 640)), 'yolov7.onnx', opset_version=12)
```

After that the model was exported to ONNX (visualized with [netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron)):
[image]

Usually it is better to save weights as `state_dict` and keep the source code that can reconstruct the `torch.nn.Module` so then you can safely use:

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('weights.pt'))
```

Comment: So I did install `torch==1.8.0`v with conda, the CPU version: https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#linux-and-windows-14

Comment: but when I run the code after git cloning the repo like you mentioned with the `yolov7x.pt` file in the same directory as the Python code and cloned repo, I get this error:  `RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.`

Comment: any tips to try? This because I am on CPU? and not on GPU?

Comment: Any chance you could comment on my answer for what I got to work? Learning a lot not sure if this file I found was just something that all pytorch repo's or users would have?

Comment: Yes this happens because you are using CPU-only version of pytorch. You can install pytorch with gpu support or use `map_location` when loading the model. I've modified my answer to include loading to cpu.

Comment: Would there be any chance you could give me a tip with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74081826/extracting-coordinates-from-computer-vision-inference